# Cordova - Android to modify JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Let me explain my problem :

I'm using a Cordova Web View with some HTML and JS.
 At the moment, when I know that I can for exemple, when pressing an HTML element such a button, display an ***Android Toast*** ( then I can do a lot of things like that ).

**BUT**

What about reversing that? I mean I have my classic ***Android button*** and when I press it, that display a new HTML ***span*** .

At the moment I can display an alert :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.cordova_layout);
    cordova_webview = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.cordova_web_view);

    cordova_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    cordova_webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    cordova_webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert(\"Hi!\")");
}
```

Is there anyway to write and/or interact with JavaScript?

For exemple, that **DOESN'T** work :

```
cordova_webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"test\").innerHTML = \"TEST\";");
```

I tried a lot of other things like that and no one worked..

If anyone can share that knowledge and maybe an very simple exemple !

Comment: The `Doesn't work` example should work if you wait for the document to completely load. try (as an example test) `cordova_webview.loadUrl("javascript:setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById(\"test\").innerHTML = \"TEST\";},1000);");`

Comment: yeah, @DawsonLoudon is right, when you put that code in the button click it will work because the webview already loaded the html, but you can't do that just right after the loadUrl of the index.html

Comment: That doesn't work :c

Comment: It will work, you just need to rewrite it specific to your app. Without knowing what methods you have available or what frameworks you are using, this is a just speculation. If you were using `jQuery` I would try `cordova_webview.loadUrl("javascript:$(document).ready(function(){$(\"#test\").html = \"TEST\";});` For the example I gave prior, try setting the timeout value high, like 5000 or 10000. It's all about waiting for the document to finish loading before trying to interact with it.

Comment: I'm just using : - CordovaWebView and an Android Button.
When i'm adding click listener then loadUrl with any JS, nothing is happening, timeout, or anything do not change anything.
By the way, when i'm using a classic WebView, it work perfeclty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bad idea trying to modify JavaScript directly in Cordova Activity..
Please refer to my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774238/cordova-intent-broadcastreceiver) using Plugin for an much easier way